# Redirect all URLs without .html and set status code 301

Tags: nginx, php, redirect, 301-redirect

I'm struggling wit a configuration for nginx. I have to add the `.html`suffix to all URLs, which don't have it and do a 301 redirect to the same URL with the suffix. URLs which have the `.html`suffix shouldn't be changed.

E.g:

- https://my.server.org/some-page => 301 => https://my.server.org/some-page.html
- https://my.server.org/some-page.html => no change/redirect, show php-based page

Any help is appreciated!

This is my current configuration for nginx:

```
    server {
      listen 443 ssl spdy;
      server_name my.server.org;

      root /var/www/Web;
      index index.html index.php;

      client_max_body_size 2G;

      # Prevent google indexing of staging environment
      add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow, nosnippet, noarchive";

      location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
      }

      include /etc/nginx/server-config/nginx-static-resources.conf;

      location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
           return 404;
        }
        # This is a robust solution for path info security issue and works with "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1" in /etc/php.ini (default)

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add something like below in your config in `Location /` block.

For eg :

```
location / {

          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

         if ($request_filename ~* ^.+.html$) {
           break;
         }
         # add .html to URI and serve file
         if (-e $request_filename.html) {
           rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1.html last;
           break;
         }
       }
```

Confirm if it works else will help you with something else.

Note : You can also try getting `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;`  outside `Location /` if it doesn't affect your application.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately it doesn't work. It seems that it now tries to find a static html file, which is not available, and doesn't pass it to the php framework. 
If I'm adding this statement the url `http://my.domain/page.html` shows a nginx server 404 page and `http://my.domain/page` shows also a 404 page but from my php framework. It doesn't redirect to `.html`